# Capybara doesn't follow redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to run expectations on `page.current_url`, however, for some reason, `page.current_url` isn't getting updated.

This happens **when I click a link rather than visiting a url**. Look:

```
scenario 'When a user who is not an admin visits the dashboard' do
    before do
        sign_up user
        visit admin_statistics_path
    end

    its(:current_url){ should have_a_uri_of root_path }
end
```

All those specs pass. However, **when I click a link to admin_statistics_path rather than visiting admin_statistics_path, the current_url expectation fails:**

```
describe 'When a user who is not an admin clicks control panel' do
        before do
            sign_up user
            click_link 'dashboard'

#           puts current_url   
        end

    it { should have_css 'div.danger', "You do not have sufficient priviledges to access the admin area. Try logging out and logging in with an account that has admin priviledges." }
    it { should have_css 'h1', text: 'Goals'}
    its(:current_url){ should have_a_uri_of root_path }
end
```

All the above expectations pass apart from the **current_url** one! Even weirder, if I put the current_url, the spec passes:

```
describe 'When a user who is not an admin clicks control panel' do
        before do
            sign_up user
            click_link 'dashboard'

            puts current_url  #=> returns the initial url despite the specs passing 
        end

    it { should have_css 'div.danger', "You do not have sufficient priviledges to access the admin area. Try logging out and logging in with an account that has admin priviledges." }
    it { should have_css 'h1', text: 'Goals'}
    its(:current_url){ should have_a_uri_of root_path }
end
```

- How do I get capybara to wait for a redirect?
- Why does putting current_url cause expectations to pass?
- Why does **visiting** a url cause the expectations on the current_url to pass?
- Why does **clicking a link** to a url not cause the expectations on the current_url to pass?

Comment: 1) use `sleep` if redirection took time 2) `it{ should have_a_uri_of URI.parse(current_url) }` 3) you already assign `current_url` to `root_path` by this `its(:current_url){ should have_a_uri_of root_path }` that's why every time it take `root_path` instead of real current url

Comment: and please fix the indentation

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming to this question now, Capybara 2.5 added a has_current_path matcher which will use Capybaras waiting behavior when checking the current_path

```
it { should have_current_path(root_path) }
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(root_path)
```